# Adding a checkbox to an unordered list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-lists

I have an unordered list (which can nest) such as:

```
<div id="checklist">
    <ul>
        <li>On Page SEO
            <ul>
                <li>My work <i>And note.</i>
                <li>Your work <i>Blah</i>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Is this love?</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On document ready, I want to add a checkbox to each `<li>` tag BEFORE the text. I currently have the following which adds it AFTER the text:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').appendTo('li');
 });
```

Comment: So, use prependTo() method instead of appendTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `prependTo()` instead of `appendTo()` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('div#checklist ul li').prepend('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />');
 });
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo("li");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to append checkbox next to any `li` that does not contain a `ul` inside it, if so then you can do:

```
$('ul li').not(':has("ul")').append('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />');
```

You also need to close the `<li>` using `</li>` in your HTML markup.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3669/)**